# no database selected when opening a php file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a table with php so I could display data from a database in a browser. I'm using apache, php, mysql and phpmyadmin. the php code is fine - all the examples I've seen on various threads show the same thing.
the problem is when I try to open a php file in a browser I get either ' Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' or 'no database selected'. this probably a basic mistake that I'm doing - but I'm a complete beginner. thanks in advance for any help.

php code below:

```
<?php
include_once('config.inc.php');

try{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_server", $db_user, $db_pw);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

print "<div><h3>Title</h3>";
print "<table><tr><th>Column_1</a></th><th>Column_2</a></th></tr>";

foreach ($db->query("SELECT sth_one, sth_two FROM the_database") as $a) {
  $row="<tr><td>$a[sth_one]</td><td>$a[sth_two]</td></tr>\n";
  print $row;
}

print "\n</table></div>\n";
?>
```

Comment: Supply code for more meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you supply an example for what you're doing?

Generally this indicates, that you forgot to specify which database to use, while connecting to the mysql server

Comment: where do I indicate the database I want to use?

Comment: Where it says database: `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");`

Comment: doesn't work neither if I put the database name in config.inc.php nor if I put it in new PDO("mysql:dbname..."). a hint please

Comment: Did you first create a database within PHPmyadmin or somewhere else? Just making sure

Comment: as I said at the beginning - it was a simple error at the very basic level

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think I read something about the right sequence of parameters to insert in the constructor.

Try with:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pw);
```

or:

```
$db = new PDO("dbname=$db_name;mysql:host=$db_server", $db_user, $db_pw);
```

as indicated here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: perhaps I should ask... where does php take the database from?

Comment: if by 'working' you mean if I can see the table with data from the database - then no

Comment: So, could you please update your question providing the content of the file `config.inc.php`? As @echolocation said, Supply code for more meaningful answers.

Comment: problem solved, I had to see how it's done properly and found my mistake. thanks for your help